# Do I need to put a comma?

Tags: выражения, пунктуация

Do I need to put a comma in this phrase "Исходя из этого можно понять(,) насколько сложно..."?

Answer (score 12):

Actually, *two* commas must be put in this sentence:

> Исходя из этого, можно понять, насколько сложно... .

The first comma is because phrases introduced by the preposition `исходя из` are [separated by commas](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_248) if they are not a part of the predicate.

The second comma is because clauses  introduced by `насколько` are separated by commas in Russian.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to put a comma in this phrase  because the clause, introduced by "насколько" needs a comma, being a separate close with a subject and a predicate.